# Isekai manga where the main character is a healer but gets his limbs chopped off

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is transported to another world and receives the gift of healing. The kingdom then kidnapped him in the middle of the night, locked him in a dungeon, and every day he gets his limbs chopped off, but they regenerate. Then one day he escapes with the help of a demon who teleports him out of there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Hello, could you please [edit] in _when_ you read this? Also please take a look at [this guide for asking ID requests](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) and [this guide tailored towards anime and manga](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/19561).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's pretty recent, this sounds like *[Boku no Nakama wa Isekai Saikyou Undead](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/boku-no-nakama-wa-isekai-saikyou-undead)*, a.k.a. *My companion is the strongest undead in another world* from 2021.

Description from Anime-Planet:

> Yuuma, a timid college student who has been summoned to a different
> world. It was thought that a fun life in a different world would begin
> with the cheating ability given to you, but what was waiting for him
> was cold-hearted and cruel treatment. His body is chopped up, fear and
> severe pain run throughout his whole body, and it is a living hell
> that never ends. “Why did this happen to me…” Aside from Yuuma’s
> heartbreaking cry, the blessing of “immortality” continues to
> regenerate his body. Yuuma was made into an experimental animal of
> researchers who were fascinated by the possibility, but he meets a
> pretty girl by chance in the facility — after meeting Eva, his life in
> a different world begins to change greatly!

If it is this one, though, the protagonist is not kidnapped in the middle of the night by the Kingdom, but instead discreetly invited by the kingdom's researchers in the early morning to aid in their research, which turns out to be having his limbs chopped off and regrown to research immortality. And of course, being imprisoned in the castles dungeons so that the other summons don't find out about it.

Also, the escape isn't teleportation, but mostly brute force, as it turns out Eva is an extremely powerful vampire that's been imprisoned and experimented on by these same researchers for years.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [*Dungeon Seeker*](https://anilist.co/manga/97999/Dungeon-Seeker/)?

OP is summoned to a new world and is kidnapped by a village where they persistently cut off his limbs until he escapes.

> Junpei Takeda, a high school student, is childhood friends with Noriko Tatsumiya and the bully Kido Shouta. One day, during the usual course of bullying Junpei, they were suddenly summoned to a different world by the whim of "God". Summoned Heroes with cheats, or so he thought. But it turns out Junpei's stats were even worse than an average farmer. Tricked into a deathly labyrinth by the only one he trust, he walks the journey for revenge.
>
> [image]

Comment: Unless I read it incorrectly, the OP only had one limb (his leg) chopped off in this story, not multiple limbs. Also, he wasn't a healer and escaped on his own, rather than being saved by a demon.

Comment: @LogicDictates - She threatens to chop off more limbs and the healing is a function of the village being a "Safe zone". He was supported by a guy who looks a lot like a demon

Comment: Overall, this seems like a pretty poor match to me. It's an isekai manga where the MC had one limb cut off, but he didn't have multiple limbs cut off, he wasn't a healer, he wasn't locked up in a dungeon, and he wasn't teleported away by a demon.

Comment: He heals unnaturally, he's regularly supported by a character who could easily be confused for a demon, he gets teleported out of the dungeon shortly after escaping by a friendly (albeit generally malevolent) god. Also, later in the manga he gains additional healing powers. It's not a fantastic match, but it's also not a greatly detailed description to begin with.